# lvextend and resize2fs in root filesystem

Tags: filesystems, rhel, lvm, root-filesystem

My root filesystem is out of space; I checked with vgdisplay and I found there are 24.81GB free PEs in the root volumegroup:

Free  PE / Size       6351 / 24.81 GiB

I have added extra space to other filesystems but not to the root fs. Is it the same procedure in this case? I mean, to use lvextend and resize2fs in the "/" root filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but if you use a filesystem that does not support online resizing, you'll need to boot from something else while doing so.

Comment: How do I know if the filesystem supports online resizing or not?